# Ambiguous/non-existen verbs in this sentence

Tags: grammar

The following is an excerpt from a dialogue between me and my language partner. For full context, I attach the full block about the topic "Your name (anime)" we were talking about at that point:

「君の名は」は、DVDを買って、家で観ました。海外での「ジブリアニメ」の定義はよくわかりませんが、日本で「ジブリ映画」というと、スタジオジブリが製作したアニメ映画のことで、その数はそれほど多くはありません。 http://nendai-ryuukou.com/article/030.html

でも「君の名は」は日本でもとても評判がよく、私もよくできていると思いました。ratwimps の歌を効果的に使い、テンポよく進んでいくのが良かったですね。 アンドレアスさんは字幕で観たのですか。私は、この映画では日本語の特性がよく表れていると思いました。男の子の一人称は「オレ」、女の子を呼ぶときの二人称は「おまえ」ですが、女の子の一人称は「私」、男の子を呼ぶときの二人称は「あなた」です。入れ替わっているとき、もちろん声や仕草でも区別がつきますが、どの人称を使うかでもすぐにわかるのです。画面に顔が映っていないときも同じです。 外見が女の子でも、「オレ・・・」とつぶやいたら、中身は男の子ですよね。 人称について話すと長くなるので、ここでやめておきます。

The sentence in question: (Here she responded to my personal experience with the anime "your name", because I told her that I first thought it was a ghibli anime due to the high quality of the animation.) 
でも「君の名は」は日本でもとても評判がよく、私もよくできていると思いました。

My attempt at translation:
"But I think that 'your name' having much fame also in japan, I also can good."

So, what poses the biggest problem for me is that in the part 日本でもとても評判がよく、私もよくできている there is a lack of verbs. 
I assumed that a て形-copula can be extrapolated in とても評判がよく, but I was absolutely clueless what to make of 私もよくできている. "Can do" for できる doesnt make much sense here, but "to appear" "to be ready" etc. also dont work well. Also, I think that "I" (meanig herself) is the subject to できる here, but in this context, where we were talking about the movie, I dont understand how she shall play a part in this.

Comment: What is so weird about saying "I think the film is ~~~."?

Comment: Nothing, but the main issue lies with the part after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verb できる has many meanings, one of which is "to be made, to be built" (#3 on Jisho). よくできている means "well-made."

> 私もよくできていると思いました。
>
> "I, too, thought it was well-made."

For common verbs with many meanings (hello, かける!), even if you use the verb all the time, I recommend you look it up and walk through the definitions; often you'll come across one that is obvious in context.

Finally 評判が良く doesn't mean "lots of fame," it means "has a good reputation." You'll see the word 評判 often in the phrase 評判通り, which means "as per its reputation..."